# DocuSign API - Adding manual page breaks in an HTML document

Tags: html, css, pdf, pdf-generation, docusignapi

Trying to add manual page breaks to an HTML document for the DocuSign API, and the following isn't working:

```
<div class="page-break"></div>

.page-break {
  page-break-after: always;
  break-after: always;
}
```

Have tried with `!important`, `page-break-before`/`break-before`, adding this to a non-empty div, etc. How can I set manual page breaks?

Comment: what is a "page" in HTML?
the whole idea of using PDF was that you may want to print. with HTML there are no pages, this is confusing if you're using different devices, page size is different etc.

Comment: DocuSign takes the HTML and creates a PDF out of it, and for some reason page-break-after is not working even though it usually does when "printing" a PDF from an HTML document (so it must be something happening with DocuSign's parsing specifically)

Comment: yes, that's a tricky one. Do you have a need to use HTML and not PDF to begin with? or is that just how your document happen to exist? if you can convert to PDF before you send to DocuSign, you can ensure the page breaks are correct on your end.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately they're dynamic templates that need to be parsed and replaced with passed information

Comment: you mean that the information is updated by a user manually? or by some automation?

Comment: This is needed in the template used at a backend endpoint dynamic user information is being passed to, to then generate the template and send

Comment: you can take the HTML at that point, produce a PDF and then send using this PDF. The point is that the page breaks would be taken care of by your app, not by DocuSign

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! PLEASE check/accept the best answer to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated:

DocuSign HTML **does** support page break within an HTML body!

To create a page break, include the following in your HTML:

```
<div style="page-break-before:always">&nbsp;</div>
```

The trick is that the block element (the `<div>`) that you want to be on a new page must, itself, contain character content.

```
<!-- the following has no content and will NOT cause a page break -->
<div style="page-break-before:always"></div>
```

~ ~ ~ ~ ~

I already know (prior investigation) that you can't specify the page orientation for an HTML doc.

If controlling the page breaks is important to your use case, I suggest that your app create the PDF itself. There are now many libraries available for this in many software languages.

Creating an RTF doc may also be an option (but first check that the DocuSign RTF to PDF converter handles manual page breaks correctly).

Comment: Hi Larry, Thank you-- this is great to know! I ended up having to go the route from Inbar Gazit due to some other CSS limitations of the DocuSign HTML API (namely, lack of support for list-style-type)

Comment: can you please look into this?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62827836/how-to-read-standard-fields-in-the-docusign-api