# How to read standard fields in the docusign api

Tags: java, docusignapi

I am implementing qsjava application of `docusign`, as part of the application it is taking the pdf file from local folder i.e,`World_Wide_Corp_lorem.pdf`. I want to take that file from my accound [Link](https://account-d.docusign.com/).

I have created the Template and I have added the standard fields like text box.

Here my question is in the api link i.e, https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/accountid/templates/teplateid, I am not getting the statndard fild that I have added in the template, from which api I will get it.
Once I got that field how can I read that my account template api and use that template in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll answer your question, but I don't think that's what you are trying to do.
To retrieve the bits of documents inside templates, you can use this endpoint:

```
GET /restapi/v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/documents/{documentId}
```

You need to know the documentId of your document, which is typically a number, if you set it yourself you can use "1", "2" etc.a

Now, I wonder if what you want to do is use this template to have someone sign an envelope using that template? that doesn't require you to download the bits.

[See this code example that shows how to do this with your template if that's what you're after.](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/code-example-use-template)